# Updating ACF field with purchased product's term ids - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to update the a 'product_themes' user field in WooCommerce/WP with a function that collects the term_ids for the items in an order and adds them to the user's profile under the 'product_themes' field at the time when the order is placed. This is working when I specify an array of IDs in the code but does not seem to be collecting the term IDs from each item for a custom 'theme' taonomy.

```
  add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_theme_to_user');
  add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'add_theme_to_user');
  function add_theme_to_user($order_id){
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $userID = $current_user->ID;
      $user = 'user_' . $userID; 
      $prodCats = array();
      $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
      $items = $order->get_items();
      $push = array();
      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
          $item_id = $item['order_item_id']; 
          $product_name = $item['name'];
          $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $itemID, 'theme' );
          foreach ( $terms as $term){
              array_push($push, $term->term_id);
          }
      }
     update_field('product_themes', $push, 'user_' . $userID);
  }
```

I have consulted the WooCommerce documentation and searched for a solution on any similar problems but I cannot seem to get this to work. Am I missing something?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you getting term_id list ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, changed $itemID = $item['order_item_id']; to $itemID = $item['product_id'];

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_theme_to_user');
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'add_theme_to_user');
function add_theme_to_user($order_id){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userID = $current_user->ID;
    $user = 'user_' . $userID; 
    $prodCats = array();
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $push = array();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $itemID = $item['product_id']; 
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $itemID, 'theme' );
                foreach ( $terms as $term){
                    array_push($push, $term->term_id);
                    update_field('product_themes', $push, 'user_' . $userID);
                }
        }
    update_field('product_themes', $push, 'user_' . $userID);
  }
```